# No such package 'slim': BUILD file not found - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, bazel

Currently trying to run Google's research, I come into the error below when following the instructions provided. [Instruction on Github](https://github.com/gcscoding/models/tree/master/research/domain_adaptation) -  Mint Linux system with Anaconda/Tensorflow download. This is the second step in "Getting the Datasets"

```
~/test/models/research $ bazel run domain_adaptation/datasets:download_and_convert_mnist_m -- --dataset_dir $DSN_DATA_DIR
ERROR: /home/.../models/research/domain_adaptation/datasets/BUILD:29:1: no such package 'slim': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//research/domain_adaptation/datasets:download_and_convert_mnist_m'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//research/domain_adaptation/datasets:download_and_convert_mnist_m' failed; build aborted: no such package 'slim': BUILD file not found on package path
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.168s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The research models, including `slim` and `domain_adaptation`, [have been moved](https://github.com/gcscoding/models/tree/master/research/slim) to the `//research` package in [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/commit/f87a58cd96d45de73c9a8330a06b2ab56749a7fa) from the top level.

However, this change has not been reflected in the `BUILD` files for https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/domain_adaptation. You will need to prepend `research` into the `BUILD` targets such as [this](https://github.com/gcscoding/models/blob/fad6075359b852b9c0a4c6f1b068790d44a6441a/research/domain_adaptation/datasets/BUILD#L25), [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/ca15f5d9dac9a0f620dcea13c412f690b04e87ee/research/domain_adaptation/datasets/BUILD#L34), and [this](https://github.com/gcscoding/models/blob/fad6075359b852b9c0a4c6f1b068790d44a6441a/research/domain_adaptation/datasets/BUILD#L43) (i.e. from `//slim:mnist` to `//research/slim:mnist`), therefore referencing the [correct BUILD file](https://github.com/gcscoding/models/blob/master/research/slim/BUILD) for `slim`.

Comment: Thanks this really helped a lot. I having the same issue further down the instructions to run the code. I know it's a directory problem but I can't figure out which files are being referenced or are referencing to. 
 $ bazel run domain_adaptation/pixel_domain_adaptation:pixelda_train -- --dataset_dir $DSN_DATA_DIR --source_dataset mnist --target_dataset mnist_m

Comment: You'll probably need to the same prepending of `//research` of `//domain_adaptation` targets to `//research/domain_adaptation` in this `BUILD` file https://github.com/gcscoding/models/blob/master/research/domain_adaptation/pixel_domain_adaptation/BUILD

Comment: Thank you again for all the help. One of my team members had the most simple idea. I can't believe I didn't think of it. We just moved the folders in research back into models. Now everything works fine. Mind blown, can't process. Thanks again Jin.

Comment: @Gabe , yes, the only quick fix I found was to do the same thing; I also had to [comment out paropts](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3819).